# Simple tetrahedron using THREE.geometry

Tags: three.js

From the example provided at THREEjs.org/docs:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3( -10,  10, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( -10, -10, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3(  10, -10, 0 )
);

geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );

geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
```

it's very straight forward to create a triangle by specifying it's vertices.  If I want to go on to make a tetrahedron using this method, I find myself repeating this code three more times, once for each face of the tetrahedron, changing one of the vectors each time to define one of the triangles which makes up the tetrahedron...

Is there a simple way, if I define the fourth vector of a tetrahedron, to create a tetrahedron without having to define each face individually?

Something like:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3( -10,  10, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( -10, -10, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3(  10, -10, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3(  10, 10, 10 ),
);

geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );

geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh )
```

Of course this code doesn't work, the last vertex is simply ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at src/extras/geometries/TetrahedronGeometry.js in the code of three.js

Copying the code here for reference:

```
THREE.TetrahedronGeometry = function ( radius, detail ) {

    var vertices = [ 1,  1,  1,   - 1, - 1,  1,   - 1,  1, - 1,    1, - 1, - 1];
    var indices = [ 2,  1,  0,    0,  3,  2,    1,  3,  0,    2,  3,  1];

    THREE.PolyhedronGeometry.call( this, vertices, indices, radius, detail );
};

THREE.TetrahedronGeometry.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Geometry.prototype );
```

Comment: I've messed around with Three.TetrahedronGeometry, but I'm looking for a way to create a mesh by defining it's vertices, not by using a base mesh and modifying it's properties.

Comment: I was looking at PolyhedronGeometry, but there's no documentation for it.  Is this a possible solution?

Comment: The code I posted is straight from the source of three.js. There are several examples of PolyhedronGeometry here: https://gist.github.com/timothypratley/1546370 and you can also look at its source in the source tree.

Comment: Sadly, it looks like this may not work anymore: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property TetrahedronGeometry, object is not extensible`. It seems modern versions of three.js prevent extension.

Comment: @SpencerD Yes, `Geometry` was removed in recent versions of three.js. `BufferGeometry` is the way to go.